# How to create public link of stored image in Google Cloud storage in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

My Image is Getting stored on Cloud but My link which I have generated is not public link. I want to access the image again from the URL but can't.

I have stored image on Cloud storage with following code:

```
List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
httpTransport = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();



AssetManager am = getAssets();

InputStream inputStream = am.open("Alternew-e82795616c8c.p12"); //you should not put the key in assets in prod version.


//convert key into class File. from inputstream to file. in an aux class.
File file = stream2file(inputStream);


//Google Credentianls
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
.setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
.setServiceAccountId("alternew-152712@appspot.gserviceaccount.com")
.setServiceAccountScopes((scopes))
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
.build();



String URI = "https://storage.googleapis.com/alter_post_images/" + "post" + timeStamp + "_" + ImageCount + "." + finalExtention;
HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);
finalPostUrlForSave = URI;

url = new GenericUrl(URI);

int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

bitMapData = buffer.array();


HttpContent contentsend = new ByteArrayContent("image/" + finalExtention, bitMapData);


putRequest = requestFactory.buildPutRequest(url, contentsend);

com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response = putRequest.execute();
String content = response.parseAsString();
Log.e("debug", "response is:" + response.getStatusCode());
Log.e("debug", "response content is:" + content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer !!!

```
 //to create file name
    //take the current timeStamp
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageName = "Image_business_profile" + timeStamp + "." + finalExtention;


    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();


    // Create a storage reference from our app
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxx.appspot.com/images");

    // Create a reference to "mountains.jpg"
    StorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child(imageName);

    // Create a reference to 'images/mountains.jpg'
    StorageReference mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/" + imageName);


    // byte[] data = CreateByteArray();


    UploadTask uploadTask;

    if (finalExtention.equalsIgnoreCase("gif")) {
        // Create the file metadata


        Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(finalimageName));

        StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/" + FileName);

        uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);


    } else {

        byte[] data = CreateByteArray();
        uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
    }

    //UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

            Log.e("downloadUrl", "downloadUrl " + downloadUrl);
            FinalUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
            MoveToNextScreen();
        }
    });
```